# Can I get the bounding box if I have just the shp file?

Tags: shapefile, coordinates, fiona

Is .shp file, without the `dbf, .shx, .prj` or others, enough to get the bounding box?

I am trying to get user to upload their shapefiles in a web page. I want to obtain longitude and latitude from the point shapefile, and bounding box (long,lat long,lat) from the polygon shapefile (both the shapefile will contain single shape/feature). I would like to think `.shp` file is enough to obtain the shape, but when I use `fiona`, it gives me an error. Is there any package that might help?

The code looks like this:

```py
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape

shp_file = 'a_polygon_shapefile.shp'
c = fiona.open(shp_file)

# first record
first_shape = c.next()

box_topY = shape(first_shape['geometry']).bounds[3]
box_bottomY = shape(first_shape['geometry']).bounds[1]
box_rightX = shape(first_shape['geometry']).bounds[2]
box_leftX = shape(first_shape['geometry']).bounds[0]
```

The error I get is:

```py
Unable to open a_polygon_shapefile.shx or a_polygon_shapefile.SHX.Try --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true to restore or create it
```

Comment: Without the .prj file, you won't know what coordinate system the data is in.  So, while you may be able to get x and y, that is meaningless without a coordinate system.

Comment: If you use that configuration option you will get an answer. Option is actually first creating the .shx file from .shp. Test with ogrinfo `ogrinfo bounds.shp --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX TRUE -al -so
INFO: Open of `bounds.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: bounds
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (500.000000, 280.000000) - (740.000000, 480.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)`

Comment: Thanks [user30184](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) for the help. Creating a .shx file using ogrinfo and then using my existing code did the trick.
@[Fezter](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/7424/fezter)I was planning to accept shapefile in `WGS 1984` only to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

Technically speaking, you can get the bounding box just from the main `.shp` file, according to the [shapefile white paper](http://support.esri.com/white-paper/279), page 4. The values of the bounding box is located at the following bytes in the file header for the `.shp` file.

```
...
Byte 36 Bounding Box Xmin Double Little
Byte 44 Bounding Box Ymin Double Little
Byte 52 Bounding Box Xmax Double Little
Byte 60 Bounding Box Ymax Double Little
Byte 68* Bounding Box Zmin Double Little
Byte 76* Bounding Box Zmax Double Little
Byte 84* Bounding Box Mmin Double Little
Byte 92* Bounding Box Mmax Double Little
```

On the other hand, unless you have external knowledge about the coordinate system, which should be contained in the `.prj` file, you wouldn't be able to use the values of the bounding box, as pointed out in the comments.

If you know how to read a binary file, say via C programming or another language, you can easily extract the bounding box itself using the offsets above.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use C. [user30184](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) comment worked for me. The plan was to accept shapefile in WGS 1984 only, so the prj file was not necessary. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get bounding box using fiona.

The minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) or bounds of the collection’s
records is obtained via a read-only bounds attribute.
https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#format-drivers-crs-bounds-and-schema

```
import fiona

shp_file = 'a_polygon_shapefile.shp'
c = fiona.open(shp_file)
c.bounds # Returns (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
(-8.621389, 49.911659, 1.749444, 60.844444)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use package shapefile, which can be found here:
https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp

```
 import shapefile as shp
 sf = shp.Reader("percelen.shp")
 sf.bbox
 [41988.03170000017, 399987.0051999986, 47011.34809999913, 402276.9079999998]
```